# which part of cylindrical coordinate system is user seeing

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

Is there a way to tell which part of the cylindrical coordinate system user is right now looking at?

I am having problems with RenderObjects that I believe are not staying where they should when user looks up and down. It works as expected on horizontal moves of the head but when user moves her head vertically objects seem to get new positions.

To confirm that there is a problem in sdk i just wanted to see if there is a way to tell which rectangular area smarteyeglass thinks right now that user is looking at so that I can see if there is a problem with my objects or the smarteyeglasses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sensors together with AR Rendering to tell where user is looking.

Infact, in SmartEyeglass SDK samples, you can use SampleARCylindrical which already has sensor listener implemented. It listens for magnetic field sensor to set initial heading.

You can use same project and you can keep listening for magnetic field sensor events. Then you can use values received, to compare against images you would expect to see at a certain heading.